# Power Bi LineChart y-values from aggregated columns

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to make a Power Bi Line Chart. y-values of this chart are the aggregated values of table columns:
e.g.: column name: 60 50 40 30 20 10. From this columns i am taking the max. values of theses columns. The x-axis has the values 60 50 40 30 20 10.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks, Andreas

I created a measure table with DAX. With this measure table it is possible to plot this line chart.

My problem: the measure table does not take filters on the visual into account

Comment: Share a data table or data model snip with the Dax that you are using.

Comment: @SamNseir here is a short overview of my table:
issue | 60 | 50 | 40 | 30 | --> Header
issue_1 | 45.5 | 34 | 23 | 78 | --> row
issue_1 | 49 | 31 | 28 | 79 | --> row
.......

Answer (score 0):

You need a table/column for your chart X-axis. Create a simple table like below:

| Scale |
| --- |
| 60 |
| 50 |
| ... |
| 20 |
| 10 |

Then create a measure like:

```
Max Scale = SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE('Scaler'[Scale]),
  60, MAX('Issue'[60]),
  50, MAX('Issue'[50]),
  40, MAX('Issue'[40]),
  30, MAX('Issue'[30]),
  20, MAX('Issue'[20]),
  10, MAX('Issue'[10])
 )
```

Then use this measure for your Y-axis.